# Too many CSRF tokens generated (PHP), how do I deal with them?

Tags: php, token, csrf, csrf-protection, unused-variables

I run into a problem. Following OWASP cheatsheet, I implemented a one-time-use CSRF token system in PHP (basically copy&paste from OWASP). Each form or link (link that generate some action) will create its own CSRF token, once it's used, it will be deleted. Application is a website, so multiples tabs could be opened at the same time.

The problem is that each time it load a page, it create a new CSRF token (even if you just hit reload and not send the form). For example, in the admin panel, there's a list of the items, each item could be deleted with a link which have a CSRF token (same CSRF token for all links), but if you reload the page, a new csrf is generated.

At the end of the day, I ended with more un-used tokens than I wanted to. This is a problem in certain servers.

TLDR; I generate a token per request. I deleted all used token (except for ajax request tokens, that after an hour I delete then). My problem is with UNUSED tokens, at the end of the day, there're too many of them.

Comment: CSRF tokens are nornmal valid for a certain period of time. If you have a central store to check against, not only check if their lifetime has expired already but also - like with session garbage collection - remove those tokens their lifespan is over. For example with a janitor job run every hour.

Comment: Also you should share the code you use (and also in any case link the resources you related to). You are probably generating too many CSRF tokens as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no (practical) way of knowing if your user will still use the token or not. Thus, you will have to automatically delete (and thus invalidate) them after x hours, for example by using a cronjob.

Just a suggestion: Are you sure that you really need one-time tokens? OWASP themselves say that it is not absolutely necessary for security: "In general, developers need only generate this token once for the current session. [...]) (https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_%28CSRF%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Keep in mind that one-time tokens also make tabbed browsing or using the browser history a huge pain.

Comment: Thanks, I had my doubts about using per-request or per-session tokens. Should I deleted them after x-time as Wordpress does? (they generate tokens based on the hour). I do not see any security improvement doing that...

Comment: What do you mean by "based on the hour"? Do they have per-request tokens that expire after an hour or per-session tokens that get regenerated every hour?

Comment: As far as I remember, they have a mix of per-session/per-request. I couldn't find the information now, but it was something like:

hash({action_to_do}_{only_hour}_{random_token})
{action_to_do} was a code, like "new_post", "edit_post", "create_ser"
{only_hour} is the hour without minutes, like 13, 14,...
{random_token} was a random number (per-session) stored in the session

to each action, the used the stored number, re-created the hash and check if it was valid. They stored TWO of those token, current hour and last hour (in case your page loaded at 13.59 and do click on 14.01 for example)

Comment: I could see that WP way it's a bit more secure, since each token has an action associated and could not be used to anything else. Due to the nature of my application, I can not control the {action_to_do} parameter.